# C# CryptoStream: Encrypt Many Sequentially - Padding is Invalid and Cannot beRemoved

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm attempting to encrypt an extensive sequence of individual values. Each value must be encrypted and must be able to be decrypted into its original value.
Rather than create a new CryptoStream for each value to be encrypted, I am reusing the existing stream. However, I am running into an issue during decryption of the individual values I don't know how to get around it: a CryptographicException stating "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

I've verified every read data block is divisible into 8 bytes to accommodate the 128-bit block size of the AES encryptor used. What am I doing wrong here?

```
            var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Key, iv);
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    long writeStart = 0;
                    foreach (var toEncrypt in allToEncrypt)
                    {
                        var bytesToEncrypt= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
                        cryptoStream.Write(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length);
                        cryptoStream.Flush();

                        long count =  outputStream.Position - writeStart;

                        outputStream.Seek(writeStart, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        var encryptedBytes = new byte[(int)count];
                        outputStream.Read(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
                        results.Add(toEncrypt, formattedIV + EncryptionFormatter(encryptedBytes));

                        writeStart = outputStream.Position;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Edit 1:
In reference to the fact that issue is with decryption yet I only post encryption: The error is in encryption but is thrown during decryption because the encryption is invalid. The decryption process works for something simpler, encrypting single values, such as something like this:

```
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
                    cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                return EncryptionFormatter(iv, outputStream.ToArray());
}
```

Decryption follows the simpler single-instance pattern below:

```
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    return DecryptionFormatter(outputStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you post complete example (which can be copy pasted and run) which reproduces the issue, in your question.

Comment: Strange that you're having a problem with *decryption* but you only show your code for encryption. Both are needed to analyze your problem. But anyway you cannot use a CryptoStream with CBC mode and PKCS7 padding the way you want to. PKCS7 pads the last block, so you at least need to account for that in decryption. Almost certainly you need to rethink this design.

Comment: To my mind the scenario this most closely resembles is disk encryption. So research how well-designed disk encryption handles the choice of mode, initial vectors, and message integrity.

Comment: I like that Idea, thank you. When I have time, I will.